# How long should I cook a 10lb chuck roast on low in the crock pot?

Tags: beef, crockpot

How long do I cook a 10 lb chuck roast in my crock pot?

Comment: There was a long discussion about the way of determining meat doneness here. [This is not the purpose of comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95937). We have many actual questions where elements of this discussion would have been on topic as answers, for example http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11739, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30006, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/43275 and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36854. Both participants are welcome to add their views there as answers. Alternatively, you can create a chat room for (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) a more personal discussion - but please keep it civil. Private rooms are accessible to moderators and flags there are handled like in any other room. I fully understand your wish to clear up the topic, but if you end up sharing valuable information, nobody else will discover it here in a long comment thread, and if you don't, then it's just in everybody's way. I would actually like to see both your expertise added to an appropriate question of the list above, so other people can find it too.

Comment: Another thing: while I don't think it's a duplicate of a question asking *how much* roast to prepare, I just realized that one of the questions I listed is a generalized version of this one, so I'm closing as a duplicate.

Comment: None of those addressed cooking in a crock pot...  furthermore the comments were more concerned with judging and correcting the OP, rather then answer the question.  Which in fact the point of this site.  Overall a great way to lose users...

Answer (score -2):

Always 145 for internal tempature.  Set on low or warm, should take 10 hours.  Similar to smoking, low and slow makes the best meat.

Not sure about comments on cooking too 160 and over, sounds like they are making leather, not meat.  If you go this high MAKE sure you have very fatty meat (like brisket).

Be sure to braise roast before slow cooking.

As comments mentioned many slow cookers are way to high, so results may vary.  I found an old model that will hold 145-150 on low setting.