# How long should I cook a steak to make it medium rare?

Tags: temperature, cooking-time, grilling, steak

I really like steak and always manage to cook it right but I haven't got it down to a fine art. I like my steak medium rare and though I always manage to get it very pink in the middle I don't know the exact times. How long should I cook a steak, and at what temperature, to make it medium rare? Thanks.

Comment: Somewhere there's a question on here asking the same question about roasts -- the problem is that the shape (thickness), temperature of the pan and other factors contribute to how long you need to cook it.  If you're consistently undercooking it, you can always finish it in a low oven (eg, 200°F).  Typically, you need to turn down the heat to cook things more.  (so the outside doesn't burn before you get the middle to where you want it).

Comment: If you want to know how to cook meat well, read http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36854/what-makes-a-moist-steak-or-roast/36856#36856 and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11739/time-vs-temperature-what-changes-what/41378#41378.

Comment: Very pink in the middle isn't exactly how'd I'd describe medium rare. Medium rare is somewhat raw-ish in the very middle (i.e.red). Medium should be quite pink in the middle. This picture should help https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/c7/5d/0e/c75d0e22cf4e77d7b7ad566a4856105f.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a 'how long is a piece of string' question. The thickness of the meat, the thickness and material of the pan, your hob type and various other factors will all influence the cooking time. So it is impossible to give you a hard and fast answer.

The best solution is to simply remove time from the equation altogether. Invest in a quick read digital probe thermometer and measure the temperature! You want the steak to be 55-57C in the middle for medium rare. It will keep cooking while it rests, so take the steak off the heat when it hits about 53-54.

Answer (score 0):

Don't time your steaks.  A medium rare steak will feel like the pad of your chin when pressed.  Press your finger against the fatty pad at the end of your chin, then (after cleaning your hands, sanitation first!), press against the middle of the steak.  They should feel about the same.

Comment: Depending on a person's build this isn't all that useful. A person with low fat content will have a much different feel to their chin than an obese person.

Comment: This has not been my experience.  I know many people, of many different builds and body types that use this technique with excellent results.