# My new pan has a max temperature of 350 F but the recipe calls for 425 F. What should I do?

Tags: temperature, cookware

My recipe calls for an oven temp of 425 degrees but my pan can only withstand 350 degrees per manufacturers instructions.

If the original recipe called for 15 minutes at 425 degrees. How long would it be at 350 degrees?

Comment: What are you making? There's no universal conversion; some things may just not quite work the same at 350 as at 425.

Comment: What sort of pan? Check if the specified temperatures are degrees Celsius or Fahrenheit.

Comment: Yeah, a pan doesn't seem too useful if it can only go to 350. Unless its like a rubber handle or something on a pan designed for the stovetop?

Comment: a "disposable (possibly reusable a few times with care) aluminum 
foil pan" would be a cheap route to a pan that takes normal oven temperatures. A secondhand store (yard sale, garage sale, jumble sale, flea market) would be another.

Comment: If general temperature conversions worked like that, you could leave something at 20°C room temperature for 10 hours instead of baking it at 200°C for an hour. Won't work.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is - use a different pan if you want the recipe's advertised results.

If something is baking at 425 F for only 15 minutes, it's very likely that you *need* that high heat to get the result you want - which is generally going to give you a toasty, well-browned exterior and a cool, just done interior.

---

If getting an oven-safe pan isn't possible, you can certainly change your oven temperature to 350 F but be aware that, depending on your oven, it may not be properly calibrated<sup>1</sup> and it may *actually* be hotter than 350 F, which means you may be damaging your pan or exposing your food to fumes that the plastics in it are giving off when being overheated. So, even then, I'd be hesitant to recommend cooking it at 350 unless you have an oven thermometer and know your oven heats to the correct temperature.

So, my recommendation would be to go even lower, 325 F or so and then start at your original cooking time (15 minutes). If this is some sort of meat (including fish) use a probe thermometer to check the internal temperature every few minutes after that. Depending on the readings you get, you can go for more or less time... if you're half-way to your target internal temperature after 15 minutes, you can probably go about 5-7 minutes more before checking but as you approach the temperature, you're going to want to wait only a minute or two.

If this is some sort of baked good (cake, cookie, etc), I'm more concerned that you won't like the outcome at this lower temperature but you might get lucky. Check it after 15 minutes and then every couple of minutes until it reaches the done test described in the recipe, whether that's poking it with a toothpick or golden color etc.

I can't give you one number to aim for because time is an incredibly poor way to cook anything, so you shouldn't be using time to cook anyway. Always cook based on the doneness cues mentioned in the recipe. If your recipe doesn't include these non-temporal cues, you're probably better off finding a new recipe.

---

For a scientific discussion of this, I recommend you read the [excellent answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/41378/33128) to this related question.

1. Note, even a properly-calibrated oven will still heat to a temperature *around* your target because it cycles on and off. So, it will likely overheat slightly, turn off the heating element until the temperature drops below the target and then heat back up again.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost I hope your pan is oven safe (all parts can be heated and won't melt in ex. plastic). To be 100 % sure read your manual or there might be a specification on the pan itself. As for the time you need to cook it, it will always vary so the universal rule of cooking is to cook until it's done. You should never follow a recipe blindly (your slices might be thicker, oven weaker, etc), instead just check your dish in 6-7 minute intervals once you think it's near cooked. 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: 6-7 minute intervals when something is only baking for 15 minutes total, is a really, really wide interval.

Comment: I agree, different applications will definitely call for adjustments in method! Think of it this way: you do it once per recipe - next time you know the exact time it takes you and your pan/oven/grill...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the temperature limitation is caused by some plastic parts on the handle, take one or two sheets of **tinfoil**, wrap the handle with it and proceed with your recipe and the original temperature instructions.

I've done this uncounted times, works fine and my pans don't suffer from the oven heat.

However, if the limitation is not caused by some plastic parts but the pan itself: throw it out and get yourself some real tools. 425 F (220 °C) are not extraordinarily high, so your cookware should easily withstand them.